# Change page orientation

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using the iTextSharp.dll in my C# ASP.NET application.  What I am after is if the count `selectedCount` value is `<=2` then I want to print in portrait.  If the count is anything else, then I want to print in landscape.  The syntax I have below will always print in Portrait.

How should this be altered in order to print based off my criteria?

```
int selectedCount = 
    checkboxlistfirst.Items.Cast<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>()
                           .Count(li => li.Selected);

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 0, 0, 5, 0);
if (selectedCount <= 2) { pdfDoc.SetPageSize(new Rectangle(850f, 1100f)); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially need to rotate the pages of the document.

Have a look at https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/clone-scaling-and-rotating-pages

(java code, but should port to C# easily)

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));
int n = pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages();
PdfPage page;
PdfNumber rotate;
for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
    page = pdfDoc.getPage(p);
    rotate = page.getPdfObject().getAsNumber(PdfName.Rotate);
    if (rotate == null) {
        page.setRotation(90);
    }
    else {
        page.setRotation((rotate.intValue() + 90) % 360);
    }
}
pdfDoc.close();
```

Comment: Would this be called pre-render, or it looks to me that this would be called after the pdf has been saved?

Comment: This method (from the iText examples) rotates all pages. You  easily adjust this to fit your needs.